# Contourf and NaNs (how to make white regions transparent)

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to make a `contourf` plot but certain areas of the data array have NaNs (only in the data matrix, the x and y meshgrid matrices are full). I'd like these NaNs to be transparent, and they are for NaNs on the boundary of the rectangle. But, contiguous NaN regions inside the data matrix are white instead of transparent. Below is an example:

Code:

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(10:50);
Z = X.*Y;
Z(10:30,10:30) = NaN;
figure
imshow(uint8(repmat(1:4:240,[60,1,3])));
hold on;
contourf(X,Y,Z);
colormap jet;
```

Output:

[image]

Hint:

Appending the above code with:

```
% Find Face
set(findobj(h,'FaceColor',[1 1 1]),'FaceAlpha',0))
```

Will find the white patch object and set it transparent. Unfortunately, the patch underneath is full:

[image]

Update: Taking the `NaN` region and superimposing the background image results in:

[image]

As you can see it doesnt cover the entire image. If I use `imdilate` it gets rid of the white area but at the same time also destroys the black border as well as a little bit of the data.

Comment: can you give a sample code that recreates this bug?

Comment: If you take a look at the code (`edit contourf`) and search for `isnan` you'll see why this happens - internally, the function turns `nans` into a special value and then uses it to draw a patch like all the others. Since the patches are stacked, setting the transparency on that patch just gets you the one below it, not all the way down to the background image. Your best bet may be to crop/mask the background image appropriately then re-display it above the `countourf` plot.

Comment: @tmpearce Yea, I've tried this. There are some issues with it not aligning perfectly. I'll append what I got to the question. It would be great if I could set an image on the white `patch` directly.

Comment: I thought I'd be able to get this to work by first converting the NaNs to a very high number, doing the plot, then deleting the relevant patch - and if that didn't work, try the opposite of converting the NaNs to a very low number. You'd imagine that one way or the other the NaN-patch would appear at the bottom of the stack - and you just need to arrange the data to ensure this. However... trying this quickly it looks like the position of the NaN patch in the stack might be dependent on the position of the NaNs in the data. But this approach might be worth investigation?

Comment: Try using [patchTexture](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27764-map-texture-to-patch) from the file exchange to map your texture (image) onto the white patch (since you've already identified it).

Comment: @tmpearce I'll look into the code for patchTexture. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Building on H. Muster's answer, I've artificially created the bands by segmenting the data (you could use a simple function to choose the bands, or create them with `contour` on a dummy figure, return them, and re-use them).

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(10:0.1:50);
Z = X.*Y;
Z(100:300,100:300) = NaN;
figure
hold on;
h = pcolor(X,Y,round(Z/500)*500);
set(h,'Edgecolor',  'interp');
colormap jet;
set(gca, 'XLim', [0 60], 'YLim', [0 60]);
```

I'm afraid I don't have the toolbox that includes `imread` so can't show the underlying gradient, but I think this would work. I've had to increase the resolution by a factor of 10 to get a reasonably smooth image.

[image]

Comment: I've been experimenting along the same line. Probably you would prefer a function like `contourc` to create the contours instead of using round, as `contourc` takes care of the patches being closed and smooth. `contourc`, however, returns only the lines separating the patches and not the patches themselves.

Comment: Yea at this point though `pcolor` doesn't even seem worth using. It would probably be better to bin the values and then use `imshow` directly with a colormap and alphamap. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 4):

Would it be an option to use [`pcolor`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) instead of `contourf`?

```
[X Y] = meshgrid(10:50);
Z = X.*Y;
Z(10:30,10:30) = NaN;
figure
imshow(uint8(repmat(1:4:240,[60,1,3])));
hold on;
h = pcolor(X,Y,Z)
set(h,'Edgecolor',  'interp');
colormap jet;
```

[image]

Comment: This is interesting - I didn't know about the `NaN` functionality for the `pcolor` plot so thanks for the response. But, I'd like to keep the contours if possible because they make seeing color gradation a little easier.

Comment: You can add `contour(X,Y,Z, 'color', 'k');` after `pcolor` to get contours. These also are not drawn for NaNs, but appear to be, however, not entirely accurate at the edges close to the NaNs. Maybe you can decrease these inaccuracies by using matrices that are finer grained.

Comment: What I meant are the flat colors displayed in `contourf` between the contours.