# contourf: plot unordered data

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I have an unordered array of size 3xN, and I want to plot a contourf plot of the data. 
When I try

```
contourf(pnts(1,:),pnts(2,:),pnts(3,:));
```

Matlab gives error. I can see that `contourf` doesn't want 1xN arrays, it prefers matrices to draw. How can I rearrange my data so it can fit into `contourf`? I don`t seem to achieve it.

I actually don't seem to get how should the data be ordered for `contourf`. Any hint would be appreciated. My data can be similar to the one found in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647727/contourf-and-nans-how-to-make-white-regions-transparent) post, but I dont know what shape will it have. Image of post:

[image]

My problem resides in not having a predefined shape. All the examples I found star with a `meshgrid` of x and Y and then they get Z values, but my X and Y values can be named "bounded random". I know that they are not bigger than a size, but I dont know more about it.

**EDIT**
data: http://pastebin.com/uUxJzttw
You can directly copy-paste it into Matlab and it will be saved as variable.

Comment: Post the data. Or at least a small representative sample we can work with.

Comment: @jucestain There it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contourf(X,Y,Z)` requires the input X and Y to be monotonically increasing, and you can use `griddata` to convert the scattered data points into a set of points on a grid:

```
N = 20;
xq = [0:1/N:1] * (max( data(1,:) )-min( data(1,:) )) + min( data(1,:) );
xq = repmat( xq, [1 N] );
yq = [0:1/N:1]' * (max( data(2,:) )-min( data(2,:) )) + min( data(2,:) );
yq = repmat( yq, [N 1] );
vq = griddata(data(1,:),data(2,:),data(3,:),xq,yq);
contourf(xq, yq, vq);
```

I tried your data with N=20 and 30. N=20 took me about 20 seconds, and N=30 is like 1-2 min.

Comment: N is number of points? damn, my Ns are about 5000 usually. That's a lot of time...

Comment: Sorry, but the result shape shown when executing your code does not fit the real points... It should be almost a square, and i get a pretty weird shape..

Comment: N is the number of points for each of x and y dimension for vq. In regards to the shape, is it the contour or the data points you expect to be square? Can you check how your data points distribute in x-y plane by running `plot( data(1,:), data(2,:), 'x')`? It looks a parallelogram to me.

Comment: It works but it is not the output i was expecting. I will accept your answer so. Thanks for the effort!! :D